# Does only a create method classify a class as a factory?

Tags: enterprise-architecture, factory, factory-pattern

In my current project, I find my self making factories, but for two very distinct reasons:

**Reason #1**: To assist my IoC container if a particular class needs an parameter that is only known when the class is created. This might also include reading data from a config. *This kind of factory contains no business logic, only initialization logic.*

**Reason #2**: The creation of an entity needs complex validation logic, and I want to keep this logic out of my constructor so it stays simple. *This kind of factory is only about business logic around the creation of a new entity.*

Furthermore, when I create a factory for reason #2, I find myself tempted to put deletion logic there as well, as the deletion of the entity is often complex and beyond the scope of the entity being deleted; however, one would be hard pressed to call a class with a deletion method a factory.

Reason #1 Example:

```
class WidgetRepositoryFactory
{
    IUserRepository Create(userType)
    {
         int configValue = int.Parse(Config.get("ConfigValue"));
         IUserRepository repo = userType == "user1" : new User1Repo(configValue) : new User2Repo(configValue);
         return repo;
    }
}
```

Reason #2 Example:

```
class WidgetFactory
{
     Result<Widget> Create(var1, var2)
     {
          Result r = new Result();
          if (var1 < 0)
          {
              r.AddError("var1 too low!");
              return r;
          }

          if (var1 > var2)
          {
              r.AddError("var1 too high!");
              return r;
          }

          r.Obj = new Widget(var1, var2);
          r.Success = true;
          return r;
     }
}
```

When I create a factory for reason #2, is it really correct to call it a factory? Is there a better term for this kind of class? Is there preexisting terminology to describe these two very distinct cases?

Comment: Do you have an example for your reason #2? I'm a bit curious as to why the deletion of an entity is complex. If you mean to delete it from a database, then what you describe is most likely not a factory, but a repository.

Comment: @VincentSavard edited to include an example

Comment: @VincentSavard the repository simply sends the delete command to the DB.

However, there is delete logic which may not be appropriate for the repository layer.

For example, do not allow a delete on a Widget which has been marked as an important widget.

Comment: I think that would be the responsibility of either the `Widget` object, or whatever holds the `Widgets` and deletes them. I'm actually not too sure how you could fit this in a factory.

Comment: The second one is a factory *method*, the class is incidental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating or deleting an entity, where the logic for both is non trivial, the code validating the conditions has more to do with a **Use Case** and should go in the layer of your application where use cases are handled.

For architectures similar to Onion Architecture, this would be the service layer.

Comment: Good answer. My application does actually make use of `UseCases`, but I thought that since multiple `Use Case`s might want to create an application, that validation logic should go below the use case level

Comment: So really the challenge is how to reuse "use case" code, and the validation logic that goes in it.

Comment: Indeed. I already have a `CreateWidget` use case, but it does more than just validation. It also manages laying down a proper audit trail, ect when an `Widget` is created. How would you go about sperating these two functions (if at all)? and how would you deal with the naming conflict?

Comment: Maybe the creation of the audit trail is its own use case?

Comment: but it is an audit trail specific to the `Widget` it also creates the various widget parts

Answer (score 2):

> I find myself tempted to put deletion logic there as well

This is a sign that you should put validation logic into an initialize method; then you can control the deletion logic as well.

> When I create a factory for reason #2, ...

Reason #2 may point else where; I think that this extra logic from reason #2 needs to be moved either into the class as another member or moved somewhere else, For example if you are reading a config, the validation may belong there.

> is it really correct to call it a factory?

In your example I might call it a SpecialWidgetFactory; assuming this code doesn't belong in the caller.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail?

Comment: I can't go into more detail without more details.

Comment: added more detail to my question

Comment: Where would this initialization method go?